# VSCode text color not organized

Tags: jsx, vscode-extensions

What is happening is the color of the text in the VSCode is not correct, other texts color are red or orange.

I tried modifying the vscode theme but didn't work.

Here's the example wrong text color code:
[image]

Here's the expected result:
[image]

These are my current extensions
[image]